# How to properly copy/paste object between folder?

Tags: unity

I'm new to unity and found some simple task can't be done here. For example in projects tab, i want to copy/paste a script from script folder to other folder. I should be able to simply select the script, press ctrl C , go to target folder , press ctrl V to paste but nothing happen. So for now , i have to duplicate it then move it to new folder then rename it. But why can't i do simply copy and paste ?

Comment: You'll generally have to modify the contents of a script as well when copying, to ensure you don't get duplicate definition errors from having the same type name declared in two places, so making the edit in your scripting IDE and using "Save As..." to save the modified copy in a new folder is also an option.

Answer (score 1):

Select the assets you want to copy and paste.  Press Control D (for duplicate), or whatever the Mac equivalent is.  Then drag these to your new folder (optional), and rename them as needed (also optional).

Comment: Thanks yes, i was doing that way. But I just want to avoid the uncomfortable 'dragging' process as sometime when i have a big nested folders. It will be tedious to drag items from 'deep' folder to another folder from different tree. I just don't believe that simple function deosn't exist. such a simple macro, i think.

Answer (score 0):

Unity does not support copying of assets, but it allows you to use drag&drop to move them between directories. It even updates references to these assets in any objects you have.

Alternatively, you can also open the assets directory with the file explorer of your operating system and move assets around, but this might result in some gameObjects in your scenes losing their scripts.

Comment: As long as you move the .meta file along with the asset, you should not lose existing references. Or, if you're copying, leave the old .meta where it was so Unity generates a new one with a unique ID for the copy.